# Do PHP static variables persist across Batch API batch items processing?

Tags: caching, batch-operations

Do PHP static variables, which do persist during a normal page request, persist between progressive Batch API runs? What about during non-progressive (command-line) batch execution?  Does &drupal_static come into play in any way?

In my application, I want to take advantage of in-memory caching across batch processes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No they do not.

I had a similar question some time ago: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/59274/1899

PHP static variables do not persist between requests.

In your batch operation, you receive an array argument as the last argument. Call it `&$context` (pass by reference), and then you can have persistent variables.

- `$context['sandbox']` preserved between iterations of the same batch task. Useful for progressive batch OPs.
- `$context['results']` preserved throughout the entire batch progress.

Answer (score 4):

Static variables exist per request, so no, they won't persist across separate batch runs.

If you need to cache data across requests in memory just use redis/memcache/etc, there are contrib modules available for each that hook into the core caching stays so you can use a familiar API

Comment: I'd like to give you both credit for the most correct answers, because both were very helpful.  However, I am giving the littler points more points, because it's the New Year, and I still feel Christmas.